For a refactoring tool, are I/O operations part of the core domain?
I'm working on a refactoring tool that makes necessary adjustments to a Rust project when moving a source file from one location to another.
Quick Explanation
In Rust, source files are known as "modules", and they double as something like C#'s namespaces. Unlike in C#, child modules are declared inside their parents. So, if I wanted to move ./foo/bar.rs to ./bar.rs, I would have to move mod bar; from inside ./foo.rs to the root module.
.
├── lib.rs      // This is the root module, and it contains `mod foo;`.
├── foo.rs      // This is the parent of `bar` and thus contains `mod bar;`.
└── foo         // This is a directory.
    └── bar.rs  // This is the target file. To move it to the parent directory, I would have to add `mod bar;` to `./lib.rs` and remove it from `./foo.rs`.

As a result, moving modules requires making adjustments to other parts of the project. Here are some of them:

Move the target file's module declaration from its old parent to its new parent.
Adjust relative imports inside the file.
Imports of the moved module in other files have been left dangling, so adjust them, too.

The tool I'm working on is supposed to automate that.
Implementation
In line with the principles of BDD, I started with an end-to-end test that takes the I/O side effects into account. I created a sample project with a "before" and an "after" state, where the "after" is the result of my moving the file by hand. My test operates on the "before" (copied to a temporary directory) and asserts the result mirrors the "after".
However, this is only the beginning. I need tests at deeper layers than just this. But I don't know how to write them because I can't decide what the API should look like. There are a few approaches I could take, and I'm not sure which one to choose.
Classic DDD
My first instinct was to create Project and Module domain entities, where a Project is a tree of modules and a Module contains lists of its import statements and child module declarations (both value objects). Moving modules can break the project, so I ought to group them together and make Project the aggregate root.
This has the benefit of decoupling domain logic from I/O. I can separate domain tests that assert the Project is left in the desired state from infrastructure tests that assert writing the changes to disk leave the files in the desired state (including things like formatting).
However, said domain tests wouldn't be very different from my end-to-end tests.

In the end-to-end tests, I'm creating a temporary copy of the project under test, operating on it, and comparing it to the "after" version.
In the domain tests, I'm constructing a Project each for both "before" and "after" states and comparing them. The only difference is I'm not writing to disk, so I don't need to create temporary copies.

Is that good enough, or should I just stick to end-to-end tests? I can automate the creation of temporary copies, and I won't have enough tests for there to be a noticeable speed difference.
Additionally, I'd be calling project.move_module(from, to) and putting all the moving logic inside Project. That's a lot of implied complexity to squeeze inside one entity. The language doesn't feel right, either: I feel like Project should be the object, not the subject.
Extracting a Move Object
Remembering Eric Evans' advice to "make implicit concepts explicit", I thought I might extract all the moving logic into a Move service. It would contain a Project (or a mutable reference to it) and operate on it. Once finished, it would spit the Project out, and I could proceed as before, asserting that it is in the expected shape or writing it to disk.
Conceptually, this feels better, but I've also introduced the possibility of leaving a Project in an invalid state. Is that worth it? I don't know.
Furthermore, both of these approaches have a flaw: a Project could be massive. I can't write every module to disk when only a few of them have changed. So, I'll need to track changes to individual modules. A simple solution is to store the changed modules in a list, but what if I take it a step further and track granular I/O operations?
Operations as Commands
If I represent every operation as a command, I can assert in my integration tests that the move returns the correct set of operations, and then unit-test each operation, I/O and all.
// Here's what an operation could look like.
// This is possible because Rust's enums can hold data.
enum Operation {
    RemoveModDeclaration {
        of: Module,
        // This is the old parent.
        from: ModulePath,
    },
    AddModDeclaration {
        of: Module,
        // This is the new parent.
        to: ModulePath,
    },
    RemoveImportStatement {
        of: ModulePath,
        from: ModulePath,
    },
    AddImportStatement {
        of: ModulePath,
        to: ModulePath,
    }
}

This turns the logical operations (on domain entities) into an implementation detail and hides them from tests, which now verify behavior instead of state.
It also groups domain logic with I/O, but is that so bad? Normally, we separate business logic from persistence, but in my case, is persistence not part of business logic? Parsing Rust source code into domain entities and then rendering them back into code is half the battle, if not more. Does that not make it part of the core domain?
In fact, I said earlier that I need tests at deeper layers, but do I really? Aren't these operations testing the same exact thing, just differently? Is this tool simple enough that I should just stick to end-to-end tests?
I could really use some advice.

I/O and persistance is not part of your business logic. Does it matter whether under the hood you use disk, memory or network? Unlikely. However files, and read/write operations are part of your business logic. It seems to me that all you need is an abstraction layer over file system (which in tests can be implemented in memory). Secondly, do not allow invalid states. This kind of errors is hard to work with. In particular returning an arbitrary list of operations may lead to invalid state. So I wouldn't do that. Unless it is an internal implementation detail, and not exposed.

@freakish So, you're advocating for the classic DDD approach? The Project is the file system abstraction, is it not? Of course, I should test that it abstracts correctly. But should I even bother, or should I stick to E2E tests? I'm having trouble determining if this project merits integration tests at all. What does it matter to the user how I perform the moving, so long as it is performed and the project on disk looks as it would if they had done it by hand?

Maybe I misunderstood what Project is. But isn't it an abstract representation of Rust project? And then Module an abstract representation of Rust module? Meaning it is more than (path, content) pair, there's a meaning inside. Especially module contains (at least partially) parsed Rust syntax, no? For me a file is an arbitrary (path, content) pair. And then project/module would serialized to/deserialized from a file.

As for moving: I'm not referring to "user" as in person using your project. A "user" is also a dev that uses one piece of your project in another place. So depending on details this may or may not be a good idea. But generally, if you serve this kind of list, and in other place you do something with it, then you need additional checks that it is consistent. Because the structure may be in an invalid state. That's why it is better to do it the other way around: your API should accept operation handlers and call them internally. That's pretty much what the file system abstraction is for.

As for tests. Is that supposed to be a tool that is called from command line? If so, then proper E2E tests would involve having a Rust project, running the tool on it, and verifying the output. Just like end user would do this. Yes, it is worth it. Even more than unit tests.

@freakish It's a CLI tool for now (used like mv), but I might add an interactive TUI in the future. Regarding the FS abstraction, you're right, Project isn't one. I misunderstood. Regarding tests, I wasn't asking if I should have E2E tests, but rather if I should have integration tests, which test Project state but don't write changes to the FS, when I already have E2E tests that do both.
